# Qt: server receiving data from a socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, client-server

I'm using Qt and trying to create a Client - Server connection. Whenever I click a button in my client application, a socket connects to the server and sends some data. The problem is I don't know how to receive the data. These are the slots for my buttons.

```
void MainWindow::func_button_one(){
socket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 1324);

if(socket->waitForConnected(1000)) {
socket->write("button one has been pressed");
socket->waitForBytesWritten(1000);
}

else {
    qDebug() << "Something terrible seems to have happened.";
}
}
```

Now, in my server application, I tried something like this.

```
void MainWindow::newConnection(){
QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
qDebug() << "connection received";
qDebug() << socket->readAll();
socket->close();
}
```

The connection is all right, because the "connection received" message shows up. So, how am I supposed to receive the data from the client? QTcpServer doesn't have any read() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is all right, because waitForReadyRead returned 'true', or the connection is not all right, because waitForReadyRead returned false after 1000ms. How would you know the difference?

Better work asynchronously with signals. Connect your socket to 'readyRead()'. Or at least test the return value of waitForReadyRead.